# React Native font size doesn't match Figma mocks

Tags: ios, react-native, figma

I have a Figma mock that's designed for iPhone 11 Pro and a WxH of 375x812 pixels. I can't match the Figma font size using React Native's `fontSize` style property, even when running React Native on the same iPhone model. For example, if I use a font size of 14px in Figma a `fontSize` of 14 in React Native doesn't match that. There's no obvious scaling factor that matches either (e.g. a 3x scale factor is way too large).

How do I go from a Figma font size to a React Native font size?

Edit: taking a screenshot of my app and Figma, running on the same device, shows that *all* UI elements (including text) are ~10% smaller in the app than in Figma.

Answer (score 3):

```
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';

const { width, fontScale } = Dimensions.get("window");

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    fontSize: idleFontSize / fontScale,
});
```

fontScale will get scale as per your device.